# Как содержание переменной разделить на 2 переменные?

Tags: .net, c++

Допустим, у меня есть такая переменная

```
String^ q = "блабла;12345";
```

Как мне оттуда вытащить блабла в отдельную переменную и 12345?

Заранее спасибо.

С++, CLI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Практическое руководство. Анализ строк с помощью метода разделения](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e3awe53k.aspx).

```
String^ line = "блабла;12345";

String^ delimStr = ";";
array<Char>^ delimiter = delimStr->ToCharArray( );
array<String^>^ words;

words = line->Split(delimiter);

for (int word = 0; word<words->Length; word++)
    Console::WriteLine("{0}", words[word]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Используйте метод Split у объекта String, указав по какому разделителю бить на строки: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: Лучшая награда - это отметить ответ, как правильный :)